# Client Server Programming In Unity using JavaScript

Tags: android, networking, unity-game-engine, client-server, unityscript

I'm new to Network programming in [`Unity3D`](http://unity3d.com/) and basically I would like to make a connection between two android devices, through WiFi using the [`Client Server Model`](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/). And I have some questions.. such as

- How it is possible to make a server with a specific IP Address?
- How can I make a client, who will connect to that server?
- How can I transfer messages between client(s) and server?

Any help would be appreciated..
.......

I have write this simple code...

```
function OnGUI()
{
  if(GUILayout.Button(" Initlized server"))
  {
   Network.InitializeServer(32,25001,false);
   Debug.Log("Server has been Initlized");
  }
  if(GUILayout.Button("connect to server"))
  {
    Network.Connect("127.0.0.1",25001);
  }
}
function OnConnectedToServer() {
    Debug.Log("Connected to server");
    // Send local player name to server ...
}
```

I have write this simple code but OnConnectedToServer doesnot give me any responce...

Comment: For your first question, a `static` ip address is required for a server.

Comment: Thanks Killrawr for your reply...But how can we initlizedserver with specific IP...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking but.. usually you can change the IP address of any computer pretty easily, by accessing the Network Properties and changing the IP/subnet/gateway. (Go to command prompt and enter `ipconfig /all`, to view the current ip address information and make sure you only change the last node of the address)

Comment: There is no point setting up an internet server, if your ip address is `dynamic` otherwise it will constantly change (this is out of your control, and you will need to talk your ISP).

Answer (score 0):

> How it is possible to make a server with a specific IP Address?

For the IP address part, you will need a static IP. If you are behind a router, that means you will have to first ensure your ISP gives  you a static IP. If they don't, you should try a service such as [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org/), which will route your dynamic IP to a web address. You will then need to port forward the specific ports to the server, which should have a static local IP for easy port forwarding.

As for the code itself, I would highly recommend you take a look at THIS website. It has great video tutorials on making a client-server game using Unity's built in networking.
http://www.gamertogamedeveloper.com/

As for your code, you don't state how you run that code. You SHOULD NOT have the client and server being run in the SAME instance. What you need to do to test this is run the Server inside the Unity3d debugger then build the client and run it as a standalone app.

Answer (score -1):

Raknet seems interesting,
have a look here:

- [RakNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RakNet)
- [unity-Raknet](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/13827-RakNet-amp-Unity-compatibility)